# 'a href' link associated with local HTML file not responding while others work fine

Tags: html, winforms

I have a HTML document where one of the links is simply not working. All of the HTML files are accessed locally by this and other links, older ones (with exactly the same syntax) are working fine, but this one seems to not be linking to anything.

**problematic link**

```
<a href="signuptwo.html"><p id="nextbutton">NEXT</p></a>
```

**CSS (just in case)**

```
#nextbutton {
    width:90px;
    height:30px;
    color:#333;
    font-size:20px;
    background-color:#54B6FE;
    border:thin solid #666;
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
}
```

**code on linked page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sign Up</title>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body style="height:2100px;">
   hello world
</body>
</html>
```

Probably easier to outline what I've tried but has failed to correct this:

- copying and pasting working links inside the div area (they worked fine)
- changing the name of the HTML file
- trying multiple versions of HTML file as the links location.
- removing any ID links and simply having a "`<a href="..."><p>...</p></a>`" link with no styling.
- isolating the folder to a different part of my PC (the files are part of a WINFORMS application that uses a browser tool. This should not be an issue as when I isolate the root folder away from the compiler, the problem still persists)
- moving the link to other areas of the HTML document.
- testing different iterations of the target page.

I know the problem is not the linked page itself as it works fine in a browser. The links syntax is exactly the same as other links I have used on the page and the filename is identical with no special characters or anything that would give a browser some problems... WHY!!!!

let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: May be the name of page you are trying to access don't match with the name on your link. Because it works for me both in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @hans I've checked and double checked multiple times.